# Error Running Flutter App With Firebase on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working through the codelab tutorial for Flutter & Firebase. However, when trying to run the app on the IOS simulator, I get this error. I have followed all the instructions. I upgraded to use the latest `cloud_firebase` plugin version `^0.7.0+2`. It appears to be related to firebase and IOS. Any clue what could be wrong and how to fix it?

```
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET cloud_firestore OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
In file included from /Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:37:
In file included from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:80:42: warning: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' is partial: introduced in iOS 8.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationSettings [-Wunguarded-availability]
    didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings*)notificationSettings;
                                         ^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:43:12: note: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' has been explicitly marked partial here
@interface UIUserNotificationSettings : NSObject
           ^
In file included from /Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:37:
In file included from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:79:1: note: annotate 'application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:' with an availability attribute to silence
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
^
/Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:95:44: warning: 'UIBackgroundFetchResult' is partial: introduced in iOS 7.0 [-Wunguarded-availability]
          fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;
                                           ^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:76:29: note: 'UIBackgroundFetchResult' has been explicitly marked partial here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, UIBackgroundFetchResult) {
                            ^
In file included from /Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:5:
In file included from /Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.h:5:
In file included from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/Flutter.h:37:
In file included from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
/Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flutter/Flutter/FlutterPlugin.h:93:1: note: annotate 'application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:' with an availability attribute to silence
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application
^
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:115:45: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
      @"oldIndex" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:documentChange.oldIndex],
                    ~                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:116:45: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
      @"newIndex" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:documentChange.newIndex],
                    ~                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:160:21: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'UInt32' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    [self writeSize:blob.length];
    ~               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:270:7: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
      transactions[transactionId] = transaction;
      ^
      self->
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:277:29: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                            transactionResults[transactionId] = doTransactionResult;
                            ^
                            self->
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:284:14: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
      return transactionResults[transactionId];
             ^
             self->
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:298:37: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
      FIRTransaction *transaction = transactions[transactionId];
                                    ^
                                    self->
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:322:37: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
      FIRTransaction *transaction = transactions[transactionId];
                                    ^
                                    self->
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:331:37: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
      FIRTransaction *transaction = transactions[transactionId];
                                    ^
                                    self->
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:340:37: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
      FIRTransaction *transaction = transactions[transactionId];
                                    ^
                                    self->
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:351:26: error: unknown receiver 'FIRSetOptions'; did you mean 'FIROptions'?
                options:[FIRSetOptions merge]
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         FIROptions
In file included from /Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:7:
In file included from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:1:
In file included from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h:21:
/Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCore/FIROptions.h:25:12: note: 'FIROptions' declared here
@interface FIROptions : NSObject <NSCopying>
           ^
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:351:40: error: no known class method for selector 'merge'
                options:[FIRSetOptions merge]
                                       ^~~~~
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:350:17: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRDocumentReference' declares the selector 'setData:options:completion:'
      [document setData:call.arguments[@"data"]
       ~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:440:76: error: unknown receiver 'FIRSetOptions'; did you mean 'FIROptions'?
      [batch setData:call.arguments[@"data"] forDocument:document options:[FIRSetOptions merge]];
                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                           FIROptions
In file included from /Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:7:
In file included from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:1:
In file included from /Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h:21:
/Users/home/files/flutter/baby_names/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCore/FIROptions.h:25:12: note: 'FIROptions' declared here
@interface FIROptions : NSObject <NSCopying>
           ^
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:440:90: error: no known class method for selector 'merge'
      [batch setData:call.arguments[@"data"] forDocument:document options:[FIRSetOptions merge]];
                                                                                         ^~~~~
/Users/home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.0+2/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:440:14: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRWriteBatch' declares the selector 'setData:forDocument:options:'
      [batch setData:call.arguments[@"data"] forDocument:document options:[FIRSetOptions merge]];
       ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?